# Does GOTO in CATCH block in c# execute FINALLY?

Tags: c#, try-catch, goto, try-catch-finally

Pretty simple question:

```cs
int retryAttempts = 3;

retry:
try {
    await getSemaphore();
    throw new Exception();
}
catch {
    if (0 > retryAttempts--) {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        goto retry;
    }

    return;
}
finally {
    releaseSemaphore();
}
```

In this example, will the semaphore be released one or three times?

Comment: Add a log/breakpoint in `releaseSemaphore` and see what happens?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I want to know what the expected/defined behavior should be.

Comment: Looks like an interview question that you want to get the answer to. Debug the code, the outcome will be the same every time

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto It's not an interview question. It's a bug in my software. The code sporadically is running extremely slow and I have a feeling that it has something to do with timeouts and unreleased semaphores. I can't simply put a breakpoint there, because, as I mentioned, the error happens sporadically. This is just a minimal example. The actual code has about 1000 lines.

Comment: Look it up in the [C# language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#12104-the-goto-statement). The behaviour is clearly stated there: yes, the finally block is executed.

Comment: @KlausGütter I know, that the block **is** executed, but I want to know if it is executed only once (after leaving the block altogether), of after each `goto`.

Comment: @AndréReichelt No, the definition is extremely clear: "If the goto statement exits one or more try blocks with associated finally blocks, **control is initially transferred to the finally block of the innermost try statement**."

Comment: the best practice about `goto`: **don't** - you should try a loop instead (as most simple implementation), or a framework built for exception recovery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`finally` will execute every time you leave the catch block. So in your case `releaseSemaphore()` will be called three times (after each `goto`).

I also invite you to read the official documentation about try-finally [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-finally)

Comment: Thank you very much. I also found some information in the official documentation of the goto statement.

Answer (score 1):

The C# specification (ECMA-334) [states as follows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#12104-the-goto-statement):

> A goto statement is executed as follows:
>
> - If the `goto` statement exits one or more `try` blocks with associated `finally` blocks, control is initially transferred to the `finally` block of the innermost `try` statement. When and if control reaches the end point of a `finally` block, control is transferred to the `finally` block of the next enclosing `try` statement. This process is repeated until the `finally` blocks of all intervening `try` statements have been executed.
> - Control is transferred to the target of the `goto` statement.

So the `goto` only happens after all relevant `finally` blocks have executed.